# Type2 Hypervisors - ignoring user programs' sensitive instructions

Tags: operating-system, kernel, virtual-machine

I was reading Tanenbaum's "Modern Operating Systems" and within the chapter describing Type2 hypervisors(those who use binary translation but no hardware Virtualization Technology) I can't understand the following phrase:

Chapter 8.3.3:

"Also, there is no need to replace sensitive instructions in user programs; the hardware will just ignore them"

1)Can't the user programs make instructions which can cause the hypervisor to be killed by the kernel?

2)Also, why is it good that the user programs' sensitive instructions are ignored?
Shouldn't the hypervisor trap them and handle them?

Comment: The related question which led me here is: in Type 1, how does the hypervisor know whether the trapped instruction was from the OS in user mode (thinking it's in kernel mode) or from a user application in user mode (making a mistake)?

Answer (score 0):

The user programs' sensitive instructions would normally get ignored by the hardware. User programs *should* never expect to be in kernel mode, so should really not have compiled in any sensitive instructions (they should instead be making API calls to the OS).

The reason it becomes an issue with virtualization is that an OS *does* expect to execute (at least some) code in kernel mode (in fact, switching to kernel mode is one of those sensitive instructions). This is why hypervisors need to handle those calls to sensitive instructions, so that you can run an off-the-shelf operating system on a hypervisor.

Related: If the OS had already had its sensitive instructions replaced with calls to the hypervisor (because it knew in advance it would be running in user mode), then this would be paravirtualization.